# Does anyone know what is the problem in this code?

Tags: c++

I'm writing an application with C++ and OpenGL. In this header file, I just want to make an object from the ObstacleSConnection class in my ObstacleS class, but I get these three errors.

1. syntax error: missing ';' before
2. unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
3. missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
   default-int

Since I'm new in c++ and I know my mistake is so simple, can you please help me.

**ObstacleS.h**

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning


class ObstacleS
{
public:
    ObstacleS(cyclone::Vector3& p);
    ~ObstacleS();

    ObstacleSConnection * sconnection;  (error is here)

    cyclone::Vector3 m_color;

    cyclone::Particle* m_particle;
    cyclone::ParticleForceRegistry* m_forces;
    void update(float duration);
    void draw(int shadow);

};

class ObstacleSConnection
{
public:

    ImplicitEngine* _engine;


    int  MAX_CONTACTS = 5000;

    int numStatics;
    ObstacleSConnection(int n);
    ~ObstacleSConnection();

    std::vector<cyclone::ParticleContactGenerator*> m_grounds;
    cyclone::ParticleContactResolver* m_resolver;

    std::vector<ObstacleS*> m_statics;

    size_t addObstacle(const std::vector<cyclone::Vector3>& vertices);
    std::vector<Obstacle*> obstacles_;

};
```

Comment: missing includes for the types used in your header?

Comment: [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not know `ObstacleSConnection` when you are using it to define a pointer in `ObstacleS` class earlier than defining `ObstacleSConnection`. That is because of the order of defining these two classes. So you need forward declaration of `ObstacleSConnection` in your code. Just use the line below before `ObstacleS` class.

```
class ObstacleSConnection;
```

You can read more about forward declaration [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/forward-declarations/).